# sourceComment in Gulp is showing path relative to computer, rather than folder

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

I have been doing sourceComments for a project I am working with and the comments that get outputted in the CSS so that I can find the correct scss file are showing paths that are relatvie to my computer

e.g.

```
/* line 39, /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/usaa/bare-minimum/framework/scss/settings/_typography.scss */
```

I would like this to be

```
/* line 39, settings/_typography.scss */
```

How would I accomplish this when this is my gulpfile.js (showing here the sass function)

```js
var sassSrc = './framework/scss/*.scss';
var watchSrc = './framework/**/*.scss';

function doSass(cb) {
  gulp.src([sassSrc, watchSrc], {
      base: 'framework/scss'
    })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      errLogToConsole: true,
      soureMap: 'scss',
      sourceComments: 'map'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(cmq())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/css/'))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: '.min.css'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/css/'))
    .on('end', function() {
      if (cb && typeof cb === 'function')
        cb();
    });
}
gulp.task('sass', doSass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible with LibSass. Answer from node-sass member:

> With sourceComments option, libsass emits diagnostics information for each selector it encounters.
>   It is supposed to be a raw debug info, hence the paths are not (relatively) resolved.
>
> On a more serious note, this info emerges from core abstract syntax tree, where resolving canonical file paths will slow down the performance of the overall compilation.
>
> For the browser dev tools aid, please use sourceMap option instead, as source-map carries relative paths.

[Link to Github discussion](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/789)

Discussion on libsass: [Link](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/1898)